# android words not fitting into cells

Tags: android, layout, android-constraintlayout

I'm designing a Sudoku that works with a list of words instead of numbers. For the layout I've used constraintLayout.
I'm facing an issue, however when a word is too big to fit into a cell. Any idea how can I fix that?
p.s sorry first time posting here. So not sure if I'm doing it the right way.

[image: screenshot of the app]

Comment: Are you sure text is only not fitting into it and there is no any other issue, From 1-10 the max letter size is going to to 5. But 5 lettered "Seven" and "Eight" are fitting in perfectly. There has to some other issue. Can you confirm

Comment: Android supports [autosizing TextViews](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview) in the support library back to API 14.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this library](https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview) in order to make your text automatically resize and fit the view.
By using this library you don't have to worry about when to change the text size and if it will fit to the view or not.
Here is how to use is:
**1) Add dependencies to grade:**
`implementation 'me.grantland:autofittextview:0.2.1'`
**2) Add your textView into your layout:**

```
 <me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    app:minTextSize="8sp" />
```